# changing parquet file column value without changing name of the parquet file so that _spark_metadata is not changed

Tags: apache-spark, hive, spark-structured-streaming

So I have a spark structured streaming job that stores flattened json messages dataframes in a hdfs location in parquet format in date partitioned folders i.e /source/wireless/active_portal/activation/dt=current date, it is also creating _spark_metadata which has name of the files it has written into the output location.
this HDFS location has a hive table on top of it.

I have to change a particular column value PIN to a default value XXXX in all parquet files without changing their names so the _spark_metadata is not disturbed

Is there a way I can change data in a column in the hdfs location either by using spark commands or by using hive commands.

```
schema of parquet files 
root
 |-- accNumber: string (nullable = true)
 |-- accountPin: string (nullable = false)
 |-- firstName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- lastName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dt: date (nullable = false)
 |-- load_time: timestamp (nullable = false)

spark metadata file:
{"path":"hdfs://HDPDEVNN/source/wireless/activation_portal/activation/dt=2022-03-30/part-00000-02b9b4f6-ea66-483e-9348-a9b87f33a232.c000.snappy.parquet","size":6834,"isDir":false,"modificationTime":1648655859206,"blockReplication":2,"blockSize":134217728,"action":"add"}
```

I tried getting all data in a spark dataframe and changing column and rewriting but that changes the name of the files and disturbs spark_metadata file now I cant read the whole folder using spark since it gives me xyz.parquet file does not exist bcoz the file name has been changed

also I tried with Insert Overwrite statement Directory statement in Hive but that also creates files with different names

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify a file on HDFS, so you have to use Hive. Assuming your table isn't a transactional table, you can't modify the data in place, so you have to wash it through another table.

Here's a dummied up example of how I'd approach this.  Writing this from memory, so it may not be entirely correct syntax.

```
create table temptable like originaltable;
insert overwrite table temptable partition (dt)
select 
col1,
col2,
'XXX' as col3
from
originaltable;
```

Now you've got your changed data, you just need to put it back in the orignal table.

```
insert overwrite table original table partition (dt)
select *
from
temptable;
```

Comment: thanks for the solution but it still changes the underlying parquet files and converts them to /work/paceline/tmp_activation_source2/dt=2022-03-30/000001_0
something like this i dnt want the files or their names just their contents.